# Haskell Mutable Array not modified

Tags: arrays, haskell, monads

I'm doing the [Project Euler's](http://projecteuler.net) problems and I'm on the [14th](http://projecteuler.net/problem=14).

I have a mutable `IOArray` to store the Collatz lengths that I have already calculated:

```
import Data.Array.IO
import Control.Monad
import Data.Array

p14 :: IO [Int]
p14 = do
  array <- p14extra
  forM_ [1..1000000] $ \i -> do
    e <- readArray array i
    if e == 0
      then do
        let col  = collatz i
        forM_ col $ \(v,i) -> do
          writeArray array i v
      else return ()
  frozen <- freeze array
  return $ elems frozen

-- an `IOArray` from `1` to `1000000` full of `0`
p14extra :: IO (IOArray Int Int)
p14extra = newArray (1,1000000) 0

collatz :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
collatz n
  | n == 1    = [(1,1)]
  | otherwise = (n, (snd $ head hack) + 1) : hack
  where
    hack = collatz $ if even n then (n `div` 2) else (3 * n + 1)
```

where the first element is the number being calculated and the second number is the length of its Collatz sequence.

The thing is that in `p14` I do `writeArray array i v` but it always has an array of zeros (0s) in it. Why is that?

Comment: please include your import statements and type signatures for functions

Comment: What makes you think that the array is not staying modified? Have you tried printing the contents of the modified cells before and after `writeArray`?

Comment: what's up with the downvotes? Clearly asked, code included, few English mistakes is all. ... Well, imports *are* missing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran your exact code, and found that the array *was* changed.

Because there are a lot of zeros at the end, you need to scroll all the way up to the beginning to find the numbers.

Actually, if you substitute

```
  frozen <- freeze array
  return $ elems frozen
```

with

```
  sol <- getElems array
  return (length . takeWhile (/=0) $ sol)
```

You get 525 which is the correct solution... more about that towards the end.

There are a couple of problems though:

1. In the line `forM_ col $ \(v,i) -> do`, `(v,i)` should be `(i,v)` seeing as in collatz from what I understand the first value is the index, and the second is the value.
2. Now that we've sorted that out, if we try running the code with `forM_ [1..10]` and `newArray (1,10)`, we get `*** Exception: Ix{Int}.index: Index (16) out of range ((1,10))`. This will also happen once you set the values to `1000000` again as there will be occasions in which in order to compute the collatz of a number, you must compute the collatz of a number greater than `1000000`. For example, the collatz of `837798` includes the calculation of `1885048` after only 4 steps. Trying to write to that index will break things.

For the second solution, you could:

- Try and make an absolutely gigantic mutable array in the hopes that your collatz sequences never go over the bounds (I don't suggest it)
- Try and make a naive version that doesn't take advantage of precomputed values (mainly to get it working, then from there optimise properly)
- Have it so that before each write, a bound check is performed
- ...Or redesign things from scratch and see if you can come up with a more elegant solution ;)

The reason why `length . takeWhile (/=0) $ sol` works is that because you used `(v,i)` instead of `(i,v)`, you were writing the **lowest number with a collatz sequence length i, in index i**, so at index 525 you got 837799, then from there onwards it was all zeros, as there is no collatz sequence which is larger than 525.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "is not staying modified".

Using this code (note that I've changed the iteration and array bounds):

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Data.Array.IO
import Data.Array

p14 :: IO [Int]
p14 = do
  array <- p14extra
  forM_ [1..10] $ \i -> do
    e <- readArray array i
    if e == 0
      then do
        let col  = collatz i
        forM_ col $ \(v,i) -> do
          writeArray array i v
      else return ()
  frozen <- freeze array
  return $ elems frozen

p14extra :: IO (IOArray Int Int)
p14extra = newArray (1,100) 0

collatz :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
collatz n
  | n == 1    = [(1,1)]
  | otherwise = (n, (snd $ head hack) + 1) : hack
  where
    hack = collatz $ if even n then (n `div` 2) else (3 * n + 1)
```

running `p14` in `ghci` yields:

```
[1,2,4,8,16,5,10,20,40,13,26,52,17,34,11,22,7,14,28,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild hunch in case this is what is confusing you: Although `p14` modifies the array it uses, `p14extra` will *not* contain that array afterwards. It is an IO action which will always create a *new* array filled with zeros each time it is run.